# How to warn the user with alert, if he hasn't performed the right action?

Tags: swift, notifications, alert

I have a photo camera application, which can scans also QR codes and read them. I also have a button which opens the link of the QR code when it is pressed. Would you please help me how to display an alert notification to the users who scan codes which are not working. At the moment when I scan a QR code which is fake the app crashes and stops working. I want to prevent that and display a notification message something like : "This QR code is not working please try another one".

So far I have created this code:

```
func openJSON(_ Person: String)
{
let jsonData1 = (try? Data(contentsOf: URL(string: "\(transffered text)")!)) as Data!

var error : NSError?
let ReadableJSON1 = JSON ( data:jsonData1!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers, error: nil )


if (error != nil){

    let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Please try another QR", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert) 
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
    myAlert.addAction(okAction)
    self.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    return
}
```

Comment: Are you getting an error when trying to present the alert controller?

Answer (score 2):

You are setting the error as nil in your JSON method, so your error variable will always be nil. Make sure you're using the latest [SwiftyJSON.swift](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON/master/Source/SwiftyJSON.swift).

```
var error: NSError?

let ReadableJSON1 = JSON(data: jsonData1!, options: .mutableContainers, error: &error)
```

Comment: try without the &

Comment: Okay what is the expected type for the error parameter in `JSON()`? Is it a non-optional `NSErrorPointer` ? Right click the JSON init method you're using and click jump to definition.

Comment: Okay, when you make the error nil in `JSON()`, do you get a compile error or does the app run? Also, what version of of SwiftyJSON are you using?